# Keeping Source Format when copy data using apache poi

Tags: java, format, apache-poi

Using Apache POI,

I successfully copied all my data, but ive lost all my formatting, eg font, foreground color etc.

heres what ive tried

```
destCell.getCellStyle().setAlignment(srcCell.getCellStyle().getAlignment());
destCell.getCellStyle().setFont(srcCell.getCellStyle().getFont());
destCell.getCellStyle().setFillForegroundColor(srcCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor());
```

tried this for font still not working

```
XSSFFont font = new XSSFFont();
                    font.setFontName(srcSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currCellIndex).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontName());
                    font.setFontHeightInPoints(srcSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currCellIndex).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontHeightInPoints());
                    font.setColor(srcSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currCellIndex).getCellStyle().getFont().getColor());
                    font.setFamily(srcSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currCellIndex).getCellStyle().getFont().getFamily());
                    destSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currCellIndex).getCellStyle().setFont(font);
```

and this gives me an error

```
destSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currCellIndex).setCellStyle(srcSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).getCell(currentRowIndex).getCellStyle());
    
This Style does not belong to the supplied Workbook Styles Source. Are you trying to assign a style from one workbook to the cell of a different workbook?
```

This is the source format

[image]

This is how it looked after i copied over using apache poi

[image]

Comment: POI 5.2.0 and above has org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil#copyCell(...) which makes a reasonable attempt to copy the style to the destination cell.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to first create a CellStyle with your destination-workbook and add to that one the required parameters from your source-cells. Then apply that CellStyle to your destination-cells.

In my experience the CellStyle object can be a little bit tricky, and the safest way is to create a CellStyle at first.

Comment: Means I should create a cellstyle for each cells in my destination workbook, and then set the value afterwards?

Comment: You want the cells to look the same right? Then you can use the same CellStyle for all the cells.